# Generating numbers sequence containing leading zeros

Tags: linux, sequence, number-formatting

I'm looking for a way to create a sequence of numbers with a number of leading zeros.

For example, starting from **00000001** to **1000000000**.

I tried many variations of `seq` but I was never able to produce a sequence with starting number as indicated to go to the desired end number.

To generate a billion of numbers, `seq` would likely take 20min on my machine o `printf` which is a ton slower is likely not an option, I'm looking into achieving this with seq only for starters if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just do it once and save the results in a file. Then you can read the file whenever you need the sequence, without having to wait 20 minutes each time.

Comment: What do you want to do with the sequence? You can pipe the output of `seq` to a loop that processes them. The loop won't wait for the entire sequence to be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a sequence with a specified format you have to use `-f` argument like this:

```
seq -f "%08g" 1000000000
```

Although you didn't specify how you want to use so large numbers it would be better to parallelize it to make a final solution efficient.

Edit:
Version without shortest representation:

```
seq -f "%08.0f" 10000000
```

Comment: This will work perfectly. Thanks a ton!

I noticed I get these scientific notation numbers (1.44424e+06). Is there a way to get just the number instead, without scientific notation?

Comment: Oh yeah. Specifier `%g` uses the shortes representation.
So you have to use `%f` like this:
    `seq -f "%08.0f" 10000000`